# MMC Extension Snap-in order

Tags: mmc, mmc3

Anyway I can reorder the extension snapins of an MMC 3.0 snapin?

I have two snapins one being 3.0 and one being 2.0. The 3.0 snapin always appears before the 2.0 becuase in the registry it appears like "FX:{GUID}" where the 2.0 appears as "{GUID}" and I belive it shows the snapins alphbetically based on guid.